# Show selected contact phone number and name in text view

Tags: android, contacts

I write some code for get phone number and name of user from contacts,but I found some problem in my code the name of user show in text view but number not show ,pleas help me - my code is as follows-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
    private Button btnContacts;
    private TextView txtContacts1;
    private TextView txtContacts2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);
        txtContacts1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_contacts_name);
        txtContacts2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_contacts_number);
        btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        People.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        });
    }
        @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
              super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
              switch (reqCode) {
                      case (PICK_CONTACT):
                              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                      Uri contactData = data.getData();
                                      Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                                      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                         String name =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME))+" : "+c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
                                             txtContacts1.setText(name);
                                      }
                              }
                              break;
              }
      }
}
```

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

`People` api for accessing contacts as been deprecated. You should use `ContactsContract`.

I've modified your code and it is working fine now. Here it is.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
private Button btnContacts;
private TextView txtContacts1;
private TextView txtContacts2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);
    txtContacts1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_contacts_name);
    btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    String cNumber = null;
    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {


                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                                null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        //System.out.println("number is:" + cNumber);
                    }
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    txtContacts1.setText(name + " : " + cNumber);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```